# Validate Image binary data for the image content having malicious data injection in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, model-view-controller

We need to validate the image file during upload from MVC application. To validate the image, we added the image header validation logic which is working fine if user tries to upload the file after converting the file type to (JPG, GIF, PNG).

**Header Validation Logic:**

```
Private Shared Function IsValidImage(uploadedFileStrem As Stream)  As Boolean
    Dim IsImageValid As Boolean = False
    Using bitmap As Drawing.Bitmap = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(uploadedFileStrem)
        If (ImageFormat.Jpeg.Equals(bitmap.RawFormat)) Then
            IsImageValid = True
        End If
    End Using
    return IsImageValid
End Function
```

But if user tries to upload the file with the malicious data inject(appended) in the image file content or the intercept the request and inject the malicious data in Image Raw then the validating image header logic is saying the file is valid while the content of the image is not valid.

Link of screen shot having the malicious data which is inject after the image content.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNnsW.png

Can any one help me to have the proper validaiton logic for the Image file having invalid/malicious content and OWASP checks.